# NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method `following' for #<User:0xab068f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, undefined, relationships, nomethoderror

I am getting the below error for line 8. Learning from ch.11/12 of the railstutorial.org. I am using rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.9.3 instead of what was suggested from the tutorial.  I've looked around for others with the same error and haven't been able to find another example of this problem. Still a newbie to rails and this is my first post. Please help! Teach me what I missed. Thanks!

NoMethodError in Users#show

```
undefined method `following' for #<User:0xab068f0>
```

Extracted source (around line #8):

```
5:       <td>
6:         <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
7:           <span id="following" class="stat">
8:             <%= @user.following.count %> following
9:           </span>
10:         </a>
11:       </td>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_shared__stats_html_erb__794775909_89084750'
app/views/users/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__961188432_91976190'
```

Full Trace:

```
activemodel (3.1.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:60:in `method_missing'
app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_shared__stats_html_erb__794775909_89084750'
```

show.html.erb

```
31: <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
32: <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
```

_stats.html.erb

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
  <table summary="User stats">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
          <span id="following" class="stat">
            <%= @user.following.count %> following
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
          <span id="followers" class="stat">
            <%= pluralize(@user.followers.count, "follower") %>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

models/relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

   belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
   belongs_to :followed, :class_name => "User"

   validates :follower_id, :presence => true
   validates :followed_id, :presence => true

end
```

db/migrate/..._create_relationships.rb

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :relationships
  end
end
```

Edit:  Here is the user.rb file

```
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
                :salt, :password_confirmation, :zip_id, 
                :country, :birthdate, :gender, :photo



     #paperclip
  has_attached_file :photo, 
      :default_url => ":rails_root/public/images/default.png",
      :url => "/images/user_photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      :path => ":rails_root/public/images/user_photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      :styles => { 
        :thumb => "150x150",
        :small  => "250x250" }  

validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

    # associates microposts to users.  The second part will destroy all posts by this user if you destroy the user
    has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy

  def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)    
  end

  has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id",
                                   :class_name => "Relationship",
                                   :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower


  def following?(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed)
  end

  def follow!(followed)
    relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed).destroy
  end




email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :first_name,  :presence => true,
                        :length   => { :maximum => 30 }
validates :last_name,   :presence => true,
                        :length   => { :maximum => 30 }
validates :email,       :presence => true,
                        :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                        :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :zip_id,      :presence => true,
                        :length       => { :within => 5..5 }, :numericality => true

validates :password,    :presence => true,
                        :length       => { :within => 6..40 },
                        :confirmation => true                       
  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end

    def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end


end
```

Here is the following/followers from:  controllers/users_controller.rb

```
  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end
```

Comment: Question marks are typically used to signify methods that return a boolean. I would remove the question mark in the method you are trying to call.

Comment: Can you add the code from `user.rb` regarding relatinships? ty!

Comment: Added the user.rb file at the base of the original post.

Comment: If I remove the question mark I get:  wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, 3.1.3 is the Rails Version and 1.8.7 seems to be Ruby Version rather than Rails. You should correct it. And there isn't `following` method in the `user` model according to what you've posted in the question. There is only `following?(followed)` method and other methods but not `following` method.

I think you're missing this part in your User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
  .
end
```

See [section 12.11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code%3ahas_many_following_through_relationships) of the online book for more details.

After adding that line, and since now `@user` will have `#following` method to call to you can say `@user.following.count` and it won't throw an error.

Comment: Corrected the rails/ruby version for clarity.

Comment: I took a look at 12.11 and saw I missed both what you had mentioned and another part.  Thank you for the feedback and help! Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
<a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
```

to

```
<a href="<%= followings_user_path(@user) %>">.
```

It works for me as I was getting same error. Check your routes.rb as well it should

.
.

```
root  to: 'static_pages#home'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :followings, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```